# Mapbox GL JS v2.0 issue with Fill Layer "Flickering" on geojson source

Tags: javascript, mapbox, polygon, geojson, mapbox-gl-js

I am having an issue with Mapbox GL JS v2. I have a geojson dataset that mostly renders correctly in the map, but certain features won't render correctly with the "fill" layer style. The fill doesn't "show" up until you zoom way in and even then it kind of flickers around. I know the geojson is valid (at least according to geojsonlint.com. I have linked to a js fiddle showing the issue with one of the features. I thought at first it might be just related to my implementation, but it still happens when I modified a Mapbox example. Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

```js
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiampnYXJyZXR0MCIsImEiOiJjanhnM3Fud2QwZnY1M3VvN3pqZHYzZzdvIn0.jaDeTWgRsKsOeojogZzk1g';
    var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'map',
        style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
        center: [-114.000, 46.31881],
        zoom: 6
    });

    map.on('load', function () {
        map.addSource('fill', {
            'type': 'geojson',
            'data': {"type": "Feature", "id": 124, "properties": {"name": "West Central Montana", "center": "Missoula Avalanche Center", "center_link": "https://missoulaavalanche.org/", "timezone": "America/Denver", "center_id": "WCMAC", "state": "MT", "travel_advice": "Very dangerous avalanche conditions. Travel in avalanche terrain not recommended.", "danger": "high", "danger_level": 4, "color": "#e32321", "stroke": "#484848", "font_color": "#ffffff", "link": "http://www.missoulaavalanche.org/current-advisory/", "start_date": "12/20 07:19 AM", "end_date": "12/21 07:19 AM MST", "fillOpacity": 0.5, "fillIncrement": 0.1, "warning": {"product": "warning"}}, "geometry": {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[-113.7133, 47.31881], [-113.73596, 47.30251], [-113.74488, 47.29413], [-113.74626, 47.28389], [-113.73047, 47.28179], [-113.72978, 47.2769], [-113.73528, 47.26665], [-113.72772, 47.2557], [-113.72841, 47.24475], [-113.72395, 47.24078], [-113.73459, 47.23612], [-113.74043, 47.23146], [-113.73905, 47.22423], [-113.72154, 47.21397], [-113.6982, 47.20768], [-113.69476, 47.20464], [-113.69785, 47.19881], [-113.69923, 47.18785], [-113.68412, 47.16871], [-113.63502, 47.15844], [-113.59623, 47.16474], [-113.55915, 47.17897], [-113.35796, 47.18014], [-113.29479, 47.18084], [-113.29616, 47.23775], [-113.30886, 47.24171], [-113.31401, 47.23705], [-113.32466, 47.23332], [-113.34011, 47.23705], [-113.3583, 47.24684], [-113.36963, 47.25033], [-113.37581, 47.24917], [-113.38131, 47.25127], [-113.38233, 47.26059], [-113.39109, 47.26595], [-113.3971, 47.2713], [-113.4019, 47.27759], [-113.41083, 47.28714], [-113.41667, 47.28714], [-113.42422, 47.29506], [-113.43452, 47.29972], [-113.42491, 47.32067], [-113.43246, 47.34719], [-113.47572, 47.34626], [-113.48877, 47.35464], [-113.50387, 47.36905], [-113.51211, 47.39742], [-113.52069, 47.40276], [-113.51898, 47.40717], [-113.52584, 47.41322], [-113.53614, 47.42344], [-113.55262, 47.41415], [-113.57116, 47.40996], [-113.57048, 47.39649], [-113.59794, 47.39649], [-113.61442, 47.40485], [-113.62541, 47.40671], [-113.62541, 47.38858], [-113.64532, 47.38626], [-113.65974, 47.39044], [-113.67828, 47.38672], [-113.67759, 47.34254], [-113.66729, 47.32765], [-113.67759, 47.3216], [-113.7133, 47.31881]], [[-113.63691, 46.96468], [-113.6594, 46.96421], [-113.65974, 46.94616], [-113.6594, 46.92928], [-113.73116, 46.92108], [-113.76343, 46.91885], [-113.76617, 46.90478], [-113.80531, 46.90525], [-113.80531, 46.89586], [-113.81424, 46.89399], [-113.82111, 46.88976], [-113.9344, 46.8907], [-113.93166, 46.91181], [-113.94333, 46.91346], [-113.94916, 46.91627], [-113.95449, 46.92072], [-113.9514, 46.92154], [-113.95088, 46.9253], [-113.95003, 46.92694], [-113.94968, 46.93432], [-113.95088, 46.93667], [-113.95689, 46.93127], [-113.95792, 46.9226], [-113.95912, 46.92084], [-113.95912, 46.91557], [-113.97045, 46.91674], [-113.97045, 46.92096], [-113.96461, 46.92225], [-113.96376, 46.92389], [-113.96461, 46.92647], [-113.96873, 46.92905], [-113.97578, 46.93198], [-113.98505, 46.93151], [-113.98659, 46.92858], [-113.99706, 46.92776], [-113.9962, 46.9498], [-113.99328, 46.95038], [-113.99071, 46.95448], [-113.99174, 46.95683], [-113.99637, 46.95776], [-113.99637, 46.96046], [-113.99225, 46.96151], [-113.99431, 46.96374], [-114.01234, 46.96456], [-114.03964, 46.96432], [-114.03964, 46.97908], [-114.05989, 46.97955], [-114.06023, 46.99337], [-114.08186, 46.99348], [-114.08289, 47.00847], [-114.06589, 47.00765], [-114.06452, 47.00461], [-114.06126, 47.00379], [-114.05525, 47.00437], [-114.04409, 47.00742], [-114.0362, 47.01104], [-114.03311, 47.01854], [-114.02865, 47.02334], [-114.02195, 47.02953], [-114.00959, 47.03433], [-114.00358, 47.03819], [-113.9974, 47.03936], [-113.99363, 47.03842], [-113.98711, 47.04018], [-113.9847, 47.04568], [-113.98006, 47.04954], [-113.97887, 47.05375], [-113.97594, 47.05714], [-113.96873, 47.05656], [-113.96393, 47.05784], [-113.96221, 47.05878], [-113.95603, 47.0596], [-113.94968, 47.06369], [-113.9483, 47.07457], [-113.95037, 47.08041], [-113.94779, 47.08217], [-113.938, 47.08053], [-113.9356, 47.08567], [-113.93321, 47.08766], [-113.92393, 47.08941], [-113.92342, 47.09619], [-113.91792, 47.10016], [-113.91363, 47.106], [-113.90385, 47.10682], [-113.8932, 47.09677], [-113.88376, 47.09631], [-113.87775, 47.09291], [-113.87295, 47.08906], [-113.85544, 47.08567], [-113.8563, 47.08871], [-113.84892, 47.09175], [-113.84428, 47.09291], [-113.83981, 47.08824], [-113.83295, 47.08882], [-113.82437, 47.09163], [-113.8151, 47.09397], [-113.80531, 47.09747], [-113.80273, 47.09806], [-113.79707, 47.09631], [-113.79433, 47.09712], [-113.78694, 47.09514], [-113.78437, 47.09152], [-113.77819, 47.09163], [-113.77286, 47.08719], [-113.76755, 47.0866], [-113.75862, 47.08882], [-113.75691, 47.08415], [-113.75313, 47.07819], [-113.75055, 47.07819], [-113.74815, 47.07959], [-113.74472, 47.0762], [-113.72292, 47.07223], [-113.71296, 47.07281], [-113.70438, 47.07515], [-113.68961, 47.07], [-113.69202, 47.06193], [-113.68549, 47.05422], [-113.64738, 47.03024], [-113.63743, 47.00859], [-113.63691, 46.96468]], [[-114.58569, 46.63294], [-114.57024, 46.64236], [-114.56509, 46.64119], [-114.55479, 46.64402], [-114.54689, 46.64402], [-114.5414, 46.6492], [-114.52938, 46.64236], [-114.52114, 46.63954], [-114.51324, 46.63954], [-114.50054, 46.64119], [-114.49024, 46.63482], [-114.47342, 46.63223], [-114.46037, 46.63576], [-114.45248, 46.6492], [-114.42398, 46.66027], [-114.41059, 46.65604], [-114.40922, 46.66122], [-114.40235, 46.6598], [-114.39239, 46.66499], [-114.38416, 46.66311], [-114.3766, 46.66711], [-114.36355, 46.66828], [-114.35909, 46.67017], [-114.35223, 46.66334], [-114.34502, 46.66193], [-114.33575, 46.66169], [-114.3227, 46.6525], [-114.32064, 46.64637], [-114.3227, 46.64166], [-114.31995, 46.63812], [-114.32442, 46.62138], [-114.32716, 46.61926], [-114.32304, 46.61171], [-114.32957, 46.60464], [-114.33678, 46.59284], [-114.34261, 46.58954], [-114.33437, 46.58317], [-114.33094, 46.57845], [-114.32751, 46.58695], [-114.32133, 46.59166], [-114.29009, 46.59898], [-114.2815, 46.60063], [-114.28082, 46.607], [-114.28253, 46.6136], [-114.27807, 46.62209], [-114.26983, 46.62987], [-114.27189, 46.6386], [-114.26605, 46.64142], [-114.26022, 46.64873], [-114.25575, 46.65062], [-114.25335, 46.65438], [-114.24717, 46.65533], [-114.2482, 46.66758], [-114.24408, 46.67748], [-114.23447, 46.68713], [-114.21902, 46.68901], [-114.19704, 46.69255], [-114.18194, 46.6876], [-114.16992, 46.6869], [-114.15894, 46.69679], [-114.15447, 46.70668], [-114.13696, 46.70927], [-114.12357, 46.71703], [-114.10949, 46.73609], [-114.10847, 46.71397], [-114.11842, 46.69679], [-114.11224, 46.69161], [-114.10949, 46.6843], [-114.17404, 46.47569], [-114.23309, 46.40188], [-114.23446, 46.33839], [-114.21798, 46.27293], [-114.22897, 46.25109], [-114.20837, 46.17032], [-114.2276, 46.13607], [-114.21661, 46.11418], [-114.1864, 45.99314], [-114.00238, 45.83645], [-113.97766, 45.80199], [-113.96942, 45.77327], [-113.93096, 45.7311], [-113.94882, 45.70138], [-113.95843, 45.68795], [-113.97354, 45.68747], [-114.40956, 45.85224], [-114.40544, 45.87113], [-114.39892, 45.87161], [-114.38896, 45.8826], [-114.38724, 45.8912], [-114.39342, 45.89097], [-114.39548, 45.90076], [-114.40201, 45.90171], [-114.41437, 45.91223], [-114.4154, 45.9225], [-114.42707, 45.93253], [-114.43119, 45.9373], [-114.42364, 45.94327], [-114.41505, 45.94852], [-114.40407, 45.9564], [-114.40098, 45.96261], [-114.4099, 45.97215], [-114.41162, 45.97788], [-114.42261, 45.98193], [-114.4305, 45.98647], [-114.44801, 45.98742], [-114.45763, 45.99696], [-114.46209, 45.99744], [-114.47514, 45.991], [-114.48509, 45.99672], [-114.48749, 46.00483], [-114.47308, 46.01389], [-114.48097, 46.02987], [-114.49333, 46.02748], [-114.50706, 46.03106], [-114.50603, 46.03892], [-114.49711, 46.04297], [-114.49436, 46.05107], [-114.47342, 46.0587], [-114.46827, 46.06299], [-114.47205, 46.07013], [-114.4717, 46.07752], [-114.46175, 46.07871], [-114.4614, 46.09157], [-114.46037, 46.09609], [-114.46312, 46.0999], [-114.46861, 46.10418], [-114.47548, 46.11347], [-114.48784, 46.11299], [-114.49848, 46.11871], [-114.50638, 46.11871], [-114.52148, 46.12561], [-114.51633, 46.13441], [-114.52011, 46.13536], [-114.52835, 46.14559], [-114.51427, 46.15415], [-114.51565, 46.16771], [-114.50569, 46.16437], [-114.49573, 46.16747], [-114.48646, 46.16557], [-114.47548, 46.16057], [-114.46518, 46.16533], [-114.4566, 46.17056], [-114.44389, 46.16842], [-114.44492, 46.17294], [-114.44389, 46.19124], [-114.44492, 46.20383], [-114.45145, 46.21548], [-114.44527, 46.2207], [-114.45007, 46.23875], [-114.46861, 46.24588], [-114.46655, 46.253], [-114.46999, 46.26629], [-114.4638, 46.27103], [-114.44458, 46.27199], [-114.42535, 46.28338], [-114.42673, 46.29239], [-114.43359, 46.3071], [-114.42123, 46.32702], [-114.41299, 46.33318], [-114.41093, 46.36541], [-114.42261, 46.38483], [-114.41574, 46.39194], [-114.40063, 46.40283], [-114.38484, 46.4104], [-114.3821, 46.43312], [-114.36905, 46.43596], [-114.3718, 46.44212], [-114.3869, 46.44779], [-114.38072, 46.45915], [-114.3869, 46.46766], [-114.3972, 46.47428], [-114.40063, 46.50265], [-114.38553, 46.50406], [-114.37729, 46.50123], [-114.35463, 46.50596], [-114.34021, 46.51824], [-114.34708, 46.52863], [-114.34776, 46.5513], [-114.34295, 46.56452], [-114.39514, 46.55602], [-114.45556, 46.55602], [-114.5819, 46.53997], [-114.6643, 46.55508], [-114.61761, 46.57963], [-114.59426, 46.61077], [-114.59289, 46.6334], [-114.61074, 46.63812], [-114.61624, 46.64425], [-114.61486, 46.65037], [-114.62036, 46.65603], [-114.63409, 46.65933], [-114.64233, 46.67299], [-114.64027, 46.68006], [-114.62379, 46.68901], [-114.62242, 46.70785], [-114.63546, 46.71821], [-114.64508, 46.72433], [-114.65126, 46.73233], [-114.66362, 46.7375], [-114.68421, 46.73468], [-114.69726, 46.73891], [-114.7158, 46.71397], [-114.73846, 46.71209], [-114.75082, 46.69749], [-114.76181, 46.69608], [-114.76867, 46.69796], [-114.77554, 46.70644], [-114.78584, 46.71114], [-114.7879, 46.71491], [-114.78035, 46.72103], [-114.78172, 46.72621], [-114.77623, 46.73139], [-114.76764, 46.73821], [-114.76661, 46.74597], [-114.76593, 46.75821], [-114.77142, 46.76103], [-114.77451, 46.76526], [-114.78344, 46.76832], [-114.78756, 46.78007], [-114.7982, 46.77514], [-114.80678, 46.78196], [-114.81571, 46.78101], [-114.82944, 46.78313], [-114.84867, 46.79418], [-114.86652, 46.81392], [-114.8957, 46.80241], [-114.89879, 46.80852], [-114.89604, 46.8165], [-114.90016, 46.82261], [-114.91355, 46.82543], [-114.92042, 46.82907], [-114.92437, 46.83342], [-114.92643, 46.83307], [-114.92849, 46.83577], [-114.92677, 46.83929], [-114.92832, 46.84375], [-114.92574, 46.84528], [-114.92385, 46.84821], [-114.92815, 46.85467], [-114.9381, 46.85667], [-114.94239, 46.85643], [-114.94754, 46.85936], [-114.94737, 46.86136], [-114.94463, 46.86688], [-114.94068, 46.86817], [-114.93158, 46.87685], [-114.93115, 46.88243], [-114.93252, 46.88765], [-114.93467, 46.89023], [-114.93578, 46.89304], [-114.9351, 46.89486], [-114.9363, 46.89756], [-114.93347, 46.90319], [-114.93115, 46.9036], [-114.92866, 46.90993], [-114.92214, 46.91286], [-114.92317, 46.91462], [-114.92591, 46.91849], [-114.92883, 46.91943], [-114.93553, 46.9199], [-114.94033, 46.92342], [-114.94531, 46.92318], [-114.95029, 46.926], [-114.95956, 46.92881], [-114.96093, 46.93373], [-114.96419, 46.93666], [-114.97621, 46.94065], [-114.97999, 46.94616], [-114.98634, 46.94955], [-114.98771, 46.95483], [-114.99286, 46.95834], [-114.99406, 46.96162], [-114.99887, 46.96561], [-115.00316, 46.97088], [-115.00762, 46.97275], [-115.02565, 46.97556], [-115.0229, 46.98282], [-115.01089, 46.98833], [-114.99046, 47.00671], [-114.9872, 47.01607], [-114.97947, 47.0252], [-114.97123, 47.03035], [-114.96196, 47.02895], [-114.96059, 47.03503], [-114.96265, 47.03667], [-114.95098, 47.04486], [-114.94651, 47.05211], [-114.93621, 47.05749], [-114.93209, 47.06404], [-114.92729, 47.06918], [-114.92214, 47.07924], [-114.91012, 47.08929], [-114.89296, 47.10753], [-114.85931, 47.12154], [-114.84283, 47.14303], [-114.82773, 47.14396], [-114.814, 47.14023], [-114.80164, 47.12808], [-114.7879, 47.10145], [-114.7831, 47.06872], [-114.7831, 47.05515], [-114.75494, 47.0355], [-114.74258, 47.00742], [-114.73434, 47.00039], [-114.71581, 46.99758], [-114.69658, 47.01069], [-114.67186, 46.99149], [-114.65401, 46.98025], [-114.65744, 46.9662], [-114.67117, 46.96245], [-114.67323, 46.95307], [-114.69795, 46.92823], [-114.68765, 46.90525], [-114.68559, 46.85503], [-114.64989, 46.81933], [-114.61144, 46.8057], [-114.5874, 46.78455], [-114.53796, 46.76056], [-114.51118, 46.75727], [-114.51461, 46.74927], [-114.53315, 46.71538], [-114.54277, 46.6989], [-114.57366, 46.67347], [-114.57778, 46.65509], [-114.58569, 46.63294]]]}}
        });
        map.addLayer({
            'id': 'poly-fill',
            'type': 'fill',
            'source': 'fill',
            'layout': {},
            'paint': {
                'fill-color': '#088',
                'fill-opacity': 0.8
            }
        });
        map.addLayer({
            'id': 'poly-line',
            'type': 'line',
            'source': 'fill',
            'layout': {},
            'paint': {
                'line-color': '#088',
                'line-opacity': 1,
                'line-width': 2
            }
        });
    });
```

```css
    body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
    #map { position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
```

```html
<link href="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.0.0/mapbox-gl.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.0.0/mapbox-gl.js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cLs2xezf/13/)

Comment: Js fiddle returns 404

Comment: looks like i accidently added "https://" to the end of the url for some reason. Try this -> https://jsfiddle.net/cLs2xezf/13/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is that you described a wrong geojson feature because you described it as a `Polygon` when it's a `MultiPolygon`. If a `Polygon` receives multiple arrays, the first coords array is the main shape and the rest of the arrays are substracted to the main shape. In your case you have 3 `Polygons` and you want them be part of the same shape, so you need to use `MultiPolygon` that has an extra array children per node...

Long story short... you need [this fiddle I have created with your sample](https://jsfiddle.net/jscastro76/zhsfL3gw/7/)...

[image]

I only structured well your feature polygons. Code is below:

```js
    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiampnYXJyZXR0MCIsImEiOiJjanhnM3Fud2QwZnY1M3VvN3pqZHYzZzdvIn0.jaDeTWgRsKsOeojogZzk1g';
    var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'map',
        style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
        center: [-114.000, 46.31881],
        zoom: 6
    });

    map.on('load', function () {
        map.addSource('fill', {
            'type': 'geojson',
            'data': {"geometry":{"coordinates":[[[[-113.7133,47.31881],[-113.73596,47.30251],[-113.74488,47.29413],[-113.74626,47.28389],[-113.73047,47.28179],[-113.72978,47.2769],[-113.73528,47.26665],[-113.72772,47.2557],[-113.72841,47.24475],[-113.72395,47.24078],[-113.73459,47.23612],[-113.74043,47.23146],[-113.73905,47.22423],[-113.72154,47.21397],[-113.6982,47.20768],[-113.69476,47.20464],[-113.69785,47.19881],[-113.69923,47.18785],[-113.68412,47.16871],[-113.63502,47.15844],[-113.59623,47.16474],[-113.55915,47.17897],[-113.35796,47.18014],[-113.29479,47.18084],[-113.29616,47.23775],[-113.30886,47.24171],[-113.31401,47.23705],[-113.32466,47.23332],[-113.34011,47.23705],[-113.3583,47.24684],[-113.36963,47.25033],[-113.37581,47.24917],[-113.38131,47.25127],[-113.38233,47.26059],[-113.39109,47.26595],[-113.3971,47.2713],[-113.4019,47.27759],[-113.41083,47.28714],[-113.41667,47.28714],[-113.42422,47.29506],[-113.43452,47.29972],[-113.42491,47.32067],[-113.43246,47.34719],[-113.47572,47.34626],[-113.48877,47.35464],[-113.50387,47.36905],[-113.51211,47.39742],[-113.52069,47.40276],[-113.51898,47.40717],[-113.52584,47.41322],[-113.53614,47.42344],[-113.55262,47.41415],[-113.57116,47.40996],[-113.57048,47.39649],[-113.59794,47.39649],[-113.61442,47.40485],[-113.62541,47.40671],[-113.62541,47.38858],[-113.64532,47.38626],[-113.65974,47.39044],[-113.67828,47.38672],[-113.67759,47.34254],[-113.66729,47.32765],[-113.67759,47.3216],[-113.7133,47.31881]]],[[[-113.63691,46.96468],[-113.6594,46.96421],[-113.65974,46.94616],[-113.6594,46.92928],[-113.73116,46.92108],[-113.76343,46.91885],[-113.76617,46.90478],[-113.80531,46.90525],[-113.80531,46.89586],[-113.81424,46.89399],[-113.82111,46.88976],[-113.9344,46.8907],[-113.93166,46.91181],[-113.94333,46.91346],[-113.94916,46.91627],[-113.95449,46.92072],[-113.9514,46.92154],[-113.95088,46.9253],[-113.95003,46.92694],[-113.94968,46.93432],[-113.95088,46.93667],[-113.95689,46.93127],[-113.95792,46.9226],[-113.95912,46.92084],[-113.95912,46.91557],[-113.97045,46.91674],[-113.97045,46.92096],[-113.96461,46.92225],[-113.96376,46.92389],[-113.96461,46.92647],[-113.96873,46.92905],[-113.97578,46.93198],[-113.98505,46.93151],[-113.98659,46.92858],[-113.99706,46.92776],[-113.9962,46.9498],[-113.99328,46.95038],[-113.99071,46.95448],[-113.99174,46.95683],[-113.99637,46.95776],[-113.99637,46.96046],[-113.99225,46.96151],[-113.99431,46.96374],[-114.01234,46.96456],[-114.03964,46.96432],[-114.03964,46.97908],[-114.05989,46.97955],[-114.06023,46.99337],[-114.08186,46.99348],[-114.08289,47.00847],[-114.06589,47.00765],[-114.06452,47.00461],[-114.06126,47.00379],[-114.05525,47.00437],[-114.04409,47.00742],[-114.0362,47.01104],[-114.03311,47.01854],[-114.02865,47.02334],[-114.02195,47.02953],[-114.00959,47.03433],[-114.00358,47.03819],[-113.9974,47.03936],[-113.99363,47.03842],[-113.98711,47.04018],[-113.9847,47.04568],[-113.98006,47.04954],[-113.97887,47.05375],[-113.97594,47.05714],[-113.96873,47.05656],[-113.96393,47.05784],[-113.96221,47.05878],[-113.95603,47.0596],[-113.94968,47.06369],[-113.9483,47.07457],[-113.95037,47.08041],[-113.94779,47.08217],[-113.938,47.08053],[-113.9356,47.08567],[-113.93321,47.08766],[-113.92393,47.08941],[-113.92342,47.09619],[-113.91792,47.10016],[-113.91363,47.106],[-113.90385,47.10682],[-113.8932,47.09677],[-113.88376,47.09631],[-113.87775,47.09291],[-113.87295,47.08906],[-113.85544,47.08567],[-113.8563,47.08871],[-113.84892,47.09175],[-113.84428,47.09291],[-113.83981,47.08824],[-113.83295,47.08882],[-113.82437,47.09163],[-113.8151,47.09397],[-113.80531,47.09747],[-113.80273,47.09806],[-113.79707,47.09631],[-113.79433,47.09712],[-113.78694,47.09514],[-113.78437,47.09152],[-113.77819,47.09163],[-113.77286,47.08719],[-113.76755,47.0866],[-113.75862,47.08882],[-113.75691,47.08415],[-113.75313,47.07819],[-113.75055,47.07819],[-113.74815,47.07959],[-113.74472,47.0762],[-113.72292,47.07223],[-113.71296,47.07281],[-113.70438,47.07515],[-113.68961,47.07],[-113.69202,47.06193],[-113.68549,47.05422],[-113.64738,47.03024],[-113.63743,47.00859],[-113.63691,46.96468]]],[[[-114.58569,46.63294],[-114.57024,46.64236],[-114.56509,46.64119],[-114.55479,46.64402],[-114.54689,46.64402],[-114.5414,46.6492],[-114.52938,46.64236],[-114.52114,46.63954],[-114.51324,46.63954],[-114.50054,46.64119],[-114.49024,46.63482],[-114.47342,46.63223],[-114.46037,46.63576],[-114.45248,46.6492],[-114.42398,46.66027],[-114.41059,46.65604],[-114.40922,46.66122],[-114.40235,46.6598],[-114.39239,46.66499],[-114.38416,46.66311],[-114.3766,46.66711],[-114.36355,46.66828],[-114.35909,46.67017],[-114.35223,46.66334],[-114.34502,46.66193],[-114.33575,46.66169],[-114.3227,46.6525],[-114.32064,46.64637],[-114.3227,46.64166],[-114.31995,46.63812],[-114.32442,46.62138],[-114.32716,46.61926],[-114.32304,46.61171],[-114.32957,46.60464],[-114.33678,46.59284],[-114.34261,46.58954],[-114.33437,46.58317],[-114.33094,46.57845],[-114.32751,46.58695],[-114.32133,46.59166],[-114.29009,46.59898],[-114.2815,46.60063],[-114.28082,46.607],[-114.28253,46.6136],[-114.27807,46.62209],[-114.26983,46.62987],[-114.27189,46.6386],[-114.26605,46.64142],[-114.26022,46.64873],[-114.25575,46.65062],[-114.25335,46.65438],[-114.24717,46.65533],[-114.2482,46.66758],[-114.24408,46.67748],[-114.23447,46.68713],[-114.21902,46.68901],[-114.19704,46.69255],[-114.18194,46.6876],[-114.16992,46.6869],[-114.15894,46.69679],[-114.15447,46.70668],[-114.13696,46.70927],[-114.12357,46.71703],[-114.10949,46.73609],[-114.10847,46.71397],[-114.11842,46.69679],[-114.11224,46.69161],[-114.10949,46.6843],[-114.17404,46.47569],[-114.23309,46.40188],[-114.23446,46.33839],[-114.21798,46.27293],[-114.22897,46.25109],[-114.20837,46.17032],[-114.2276,46.13607],[-114.21661,46.11418],[-114.1864,45.99314],[-114.00238,45.83645],[-113.97766,45.80199],[-113.96942,45.77327],[-113.93096,45.7311],[-113.94882,45.70138],[-113.95843,45.68795],[-113.97354,45.68747],[-114.40956,45.85224],[-114.40544,45.87113],[-114.39892,45.87161],[-114.38896,45.8826],[-114.38724,45.8912],[-114.39342,45.89097],[-114.39548,45.90076],[-114.40201,45.90171],[-114.41437,45.91223],[-114.4154,45.9225],[-114.42707,45.93253],[-114.43119,45.9373],[-114.42364,45.94327],[-114.41505,45.94852],[-114.40407,45.9564],[-114.40098,45.96261],[-114.4099,45.97215],[-114.41162,45.97788],[-114.42261,45.98193],[-114.4305,45.98647],[-114.44801,45.98742],[-114.45763,45.99696],[-114.46209,45.99744],[-114.47514,45.991],[-114.48509,45.99672],[-114.48749,46.00483],[-114.47308,46.01389],[-114.48097,46.02987],[-114.49333,46.02748],[-114.50706,46.03106],[-114.50603,46.03892],[-114.49711,46.04297],[-114.49436,46.05107],[-114.47342,46.0587],[-114.46827,46.06299],[-114.47205,46.07013],[-114.4717,46.07752],[-114.46175,46.07871],[-114.4614,46.09157],[-114.46037,46.09609],[-114.46312,46.0999],[-114.46861,46.10418],[-114.47548,46.11347],[-114.48784,46.11299],[-114.49848,46.11871],[-114.50638,46.11871],[-114.52148,46.12561],[-114.51633,46.13441],[-114.52011,46.13536],[-114.52835,46.14559],[-114.51427,46.15415],[-114.51565,46.16771],[-114.50569,46.16437],[-114.49573,46.16747],[-114.48646,46.16557],[-114.47548,46.16057],[-114.46518,46.16533],[-114.4566,46.17056],[-114.44389,46.16842],[-114.44492,46.17294],[-114.44389,46.19124],[-114.44492,46.20383],[-114.45145,46.21548],[-114.44527,46.2207],[-114.45007,46.23875],[-114.46861,46.24588],[-114.46655,46.253],[-114.46999,46.26629],[-114.4638,46.27103],[-114.44458,46.27199],[-114.42535,46.28338],[-114.42673,46.29239],[-114.43359,46.3071],[-114.42123,46.32702],[-114.41299,46.33318],[-114.41093,46.36541],[-114.42261,46.38483],[-114.41574,46.39194],[-114.40063,46.40283],[-114.38484,46.4104],[-114.3821,46.43312],[-114.36905,46.43596],[-114.3718,46.44212],[-114.3869,46.44779],[-114.38072,46.45915],[-114.3869,46.46766],[-114.3972,46.47428],[-114.40063,46.50265],[-114.38553,46.50406],[-114.37729,46.50123],[-114.35463,46.50596],[-114.34021,46.51824],[-114.34708,46.52863],[-114.34776,46.5513],[-114.34295,46.56452],[-114.39514,46.55602],[-114.45556,46.55602],[-114.5819,46.53997],[-114.6643,46.55508],[-114.61761,46.57963],[-114.59426,46.61077],[-114.59289,46.6334],[-114.61074,46.63812],[-114.61624,46.64425],[-114.61486,46.65037],[-114.62036,46.65603],[-114.63409,46.65933],[-114.64233,46.67299],[-114.64027,46.68006],[-114.62379,46.68901],[-114.62242,46.70785],[-114.63546,46.71821],[-114.64508,46.72433],[-114.65126,46.73233],[-114.66362,46.7375],[-114.68421,46.73468],[-114.69726,46.73891],[-114.7158,46.71397],[-114.73846,46.71209],[-114.75082,46.69749],[-114.76181,46.69608],[-114.76867,46.69796],[-114.77554,46.70644],[-114.78584,46.71114],[-114.7879,46.71491],[-114.78035,46.72103],[-114.78172,46.72621],[-114.77623,46.73139],[-114.76764,46.73821],[-114.76661,46.74597],[-114.76593,46.75821],[-114.77142,46.76103],[-114.77451,46.76526],[-114.78344,46.76832],[-114.78756,46.78007],[-114.7982,46.77514],[-114.80678,46.78196],[-114.81571,46.78101],[-114.82944,46.78313],[-114.84867,46.79418],[-114.86652,46.81392],[-114.8957,46.80241],[-114.89879,46.80852],[-114.89604,46.8165],[-114.90016,46.82261],[-114.91355,46.82543],[-114.92042,46.82907],[-114.92437,46.83342],[-114.92643,46.83307],[-114.92849,46.83577],[-114.92677,46.83929],[-114.92832,46.84375],[-114.92574,46.84528],[-114.92385,46.84821],[-114.92815,46.85467],[-114.9381,46.85667],[-114.94239,46.85643],[-114.94754,46.85936],[-114.94737,46.86136],[-114.94463,46.86688],[-114.94068,46.86817],[-114.93158,46.87685],[-114.93115,46.88243],[-114.93252,46.88765],[-114.93467,46.89023],[-114.93578,46.89304],[-114.9351,46.89486],[-114.9363,46.89756],[-114.93347,46.90319],[-114.93115,46.9036],[-114.92866,46.90993],[-114.92214,46.91286],[-114.92317,46.91462],[-114.92591,46.91849],[-114.92883,46.91943],[-114.93553,46.9199],[-114.94033,46.92342],[-114.94531,46.92318],[-114.95029,46.926],[-114.95956,46.92881],[-114.96093,46.93373],[-114.96419,46.93666],[-114.97621,46.94065],[-114.97999,46.94616],[-114.98634,46.94955],[-114.98771,46.95483],[-114.99286,46.95834],[-114.99406,46.96162],[-114.99887,46.96561],[-115.00316,46.97088],[-115.00762,46.97275],[-115.02565,46.97556],[-115.0229,46.98282],[-115.01089,46.98833],[-114.99046,47.00671],[-114.9872,47.01607],[-114.97947,47.0252],[-114.97123,47.03035],[-114.96196,47.02895],[-114.96059,47.03503],[-114.96265,47.03667],[-114.95098,47.04486],[-114.94651,47.05211],[-114.93621,47.05749],[-114.93209,47.06404],[-114.92729,47.06918],[-114.92214,47.07924],[-114.91012,47.08929],[-114.89296,47.10753],[-114.85931,47.12154],[-114.84283,47.14303],[-114.82773,47.14396],[-114.814,47.14023],[-114.80164,47.12808],[-114.7879,47.10145],[-114.7831,47.06872],[-114.7831,47.05515],[-114.75494,47.0355],[-114.74258,47.00742],[-114.73434,47.00039],[-114.71581,46.99758],[-114.69658,47.01069],[-114.67186,46.99149],[-114.65401,46.98025],[-114.65744,46.9662],[-114.67117,46.96245],[-114.67323,46.95307],[-114.69795,46.92823],[-114.68765,46.90525],[-114.68559,46.85503],[-114.64989,46.81933],[-114.61144,46.8057],[-114.5874,46.78455],[-114.53796,46.76056],[-114.51118,46.75727],[-114.51461,46.74927],[-114.53315,46.71538],[-114.54277,46.6989],[-114.57366,46.67347],[-114.57778,46.65509],[-114.58569,46.63294]]]],"type":"MultiPolygon"},"type":"Feature","properties":{}}
        });
        map.addLayer({
            'id': 'poly-fill',
            'type': 'fill',
            'source': 'fill',
            'minzoom': 0,
            'maxzoom': 22,
            'layout': {},
            'paint': {
                'fill-color': '#088',
                'fill-opacity': 0.8
            }
        });
        map.addLayer({
            'id': 'poly-line',
            'type': 'line',
            'source': 'fill',
            'layout': {},
            'paint': {
                'line-color': '#088',
                'line-opacity': 1,
                'line-width': 2
            }
        });
    });
```

If this answer solves your question, please mark it as **answer accepted**, in that way it will also help other users to know it was the right solution.